# how to return the result of a method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

i'm working on a test class and its giving a false positive. i wish to assert the result of the method being tested to see what the failure message is.

my test class ends with this

```
Test.startTest();
LifeLargeCaseReviewCtrl.createLLCRCase(caseObj, policyList, propObj, cdl.Id);
Test.stopTest();
```

how can i gather the return value of `createLLCRCase()` and write an assertion against it to get the message?

Comment: What is the data type of the return of `LifeLargeCaseReviewCtrl.createLLCRCase()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your other question here: [can't seem to get proper code coverage. any ideas?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/325591/660) your method returns a string.

```
Test.startTest();
String returnData = LifeLargeCaseReviewCtrl.createLLCRCase(caseObj, policyList, propObj, cdl.Id);
Test.stopTest();
System.assertEquals('Success', returnData, 'Case was not able to be created.');
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!